# xpath where clause

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to build an xpath query on the following xml file:

```
<recordGroup>
    <records>
        <year>1985</year>   
        <album>
            <name> album1 </name>
            <artist>artist1 </artist>
            <label> labelA</label>
        </album>    
        <album>
            <name>album2 </name>
            <artist>artist2 </artist>
            <label> labelB</label>
        </album>    
    </records>      
    <records>
        <year>1986</year>   
        <album>
            <name>album3 </name>
            <artist> artist1 </artist>
            <label>labelC</label>
        </album>    
        <album>
            <name>album4 </name>
            <artist>artist2</artist>
            <label> labelA</label>
        </album>    
    </records>

</recordGroup>
```

I want to retrieve the following query: select all records (artist, name & year) where label = 'LabelA'.

The XML structure might not be appropiate to display this data but I am getting this stream from another software so, I cannot change it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will bring back the full `records` that contain an album with a label of ***labelA***

```
//records[album/label='labelA']
```

---

You could also use

```
//records[album/label='labelA']/*[self::year or self::album[label='labelA']]
```

that will return only the `year` and the full `album` that matches the ***labelA***

Comment: I came up with a really nasty solution that I won't use as your solution looks more efficient than mine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> var = doc(/recordGroup/records[album[@label="LabelA"]]);